# How to get the width of a html element inside an element with overflow scroll

Tags: html, css, width, horizontal-scrolling

I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .item {
          width: 500px;
          min-width: 500px;
          background-color: brown;
          padding: 10px;
          border: 5px solid white;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        .wrapper {
          width:100%;
          overflow-y:scroll;
          white-space:nowrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="me">
        <div class="item">..</div>
        <div class="item">..</div>
        <div class="item">..</div>
        <div class="item">..</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I try the following:

```
>screen.width
1440
>document.getElementById("me").getBoundingClientRect();
bottom: 56, height: 48, left: 8, right: 1415, top: 8, width: 1407
```

I would expect the width to be at least 2000 (4X500) plus padding and such.

Instead it gives me the screen width. I will fill the "me" element with a variable amount of elements that will have to scroll horizontally and need the width of the element.

Since the content is variable I cannot set it to a fixed with and instead want to use 100% of the screen width for the container and calculate the width of the content (needed for a custom scroll bar.)

Thank you for taking the time to read this question.

**[update]**

As for Alvaro's excelent answer; here is an example of the code I plan to use (sorry for the jQuery):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .item {
          width: 470px;
          min-width: 470px;
          background-color: brown;
          padding: 10px;
          border: 5px solid white;
          display: table-cell;
        }
        .wrapper {
          width:100%;
          overflow-y:scroll;
          white-space:nowrap;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function addItem(){
          $("#me").append('<div class="item">..</div>');
          var box = $("#me")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
          output(box);
        }
        function removeItem(){
          $("#me .item").eq(0).remove();
          var box = $("#me")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
          output(box);
        }
        function output(box){
          console.log("width is:",(box.left-box.right)*-1);
          $("#output").html("width is:"+(box.left-box.right)*-1);
        }
        $("#ADD").on("click",addItem);
        $("#REMOVE").on("click",removeItem);
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="me" style="float:left">
        <div class="item">..</div>
        <div class="item">..</div>
        <div class="item">..</div>
        <div class="item">..</div>
        <div class="item">..</div>
        <div class="item">..</div>
        <div class="item">..</div>
        <div class="item">..</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <input type="button" id="ADD" value="ADD" />
    <input type="button" id="REMOVE" value="REMOVE" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add:

```
#me {float:left;}
```

`javascript` may give you the right width of your element insteed of the window's width.

I tested it with this `jquery`:

```
var meWidth = $('#me').outerWidth(true );
$('.test').css({
    'width': meWidth + 'px'
});
```

Adding the width obtain to a `div` I called `.test`

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/5rsb6jmo/)**

Note: `outerWidth(true )` calculate width + padding + border + margin. In your example: 2132px.

Comment: That did the trick, I updated the answer with code I am planning to use. Too bad the `white-space:nowrap;` does not work in IE

Comment: Glad I could help and gl with your project... (btw, as long as I know white space property do work under IE (if 8 of above).

Comment: Well, as of August 2015 just 6.6% of the world use IE (any version) and ie7 is used just 0.2%. I don't think any of us should spend any resources, time and money making webs for ie7 (and it is so difficult), but ofc, it's not my call, Hope you don't have any of "those" type of clients :)  : http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: I know but 99.9% of my clients use it since they are located in Redmond and are the creators of IE ;-) I'm just happy it works for IE 8 and up so can continue to use this solution. Was affraid I'd be stuck with figuring out the with based on the json data but that would give me a huge headache every time I change the UI design. IE8 is good enough since most desktops are up to date and use nothing less than IE11